# Set up local database for use with Node.Js with Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, database, node.js, visual-studio-2015, local-database

I've been trying to learn Node.js recently, and I now want to access a database, which I use [this](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) library for. Problem is that I want to create a database on my computer and connect to it from my node.js program, but I can't for my life figure out how this is done!

In my solution I added a **SQL Server Database Project**, and tried to connect using this following string:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'me',
password : 'secret',
database : 'Database1'
});
```

But I'm getting an exception saying `error connecting: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`, which is thrown by some timeout (which I figure is because of the database isn't visible or something?).
So my question is how do I set this up so I can work with data in Visual Studio, without having to rent a server to host my database?
I'm not even sure I'm using the right project-template for my database, but I cannot see any other type of it. From what I've read on the Internet I see that there usually is some other template you should use to create a database.

I really don't know what to do, so any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be an issue with the port.

This might help you out:
[Cannot connect to SQL Server with Node.js and Tedious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315817/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-with-node-js-and-tedious)